# Output Without Additional File From a MapReduce Job in Hadoop

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2

How to generate output from a MapReduce job without having the additional _SUCCESS file in the output repository?

Answer (score 1):

use this property in your java program.
conf.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false");